# How To Install Nginx On Ubuntu 20.04 For HLS Live Streamign From OBS?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-live-streaming, nginx-config, live-streaming

HI there I want to host hls live streaming on my vps ubuntu 20.04 but i have tried many methods but unable to get install the server some times nginx does not install and some time obs do not send video to the nginx server Iam willing to find this method but no article is helping me so i need your help if  you can provide me the right codes and commands to install the server

Help me to find the solution for this problem

Comment: Maybe you can try this https://blog.ossrs.io/how-to-setup-a-video-streaming-service-by-1-click-e9fe6f314ac6